Acessing input names of a node group
I'm trying to make a list of inputs to a GeometryNode Node I created. I've done this before in Blender 3.6 like so:
input_names = [input.name for input in bpy.data.node_groups["Neuron"].inputs if input.name != "Geometry"]
Neuron is the name of the Node Tree I've created. The problem with this line of Python code is that it doesn't work in Blender 4.1. Apparently bpy.data.node_groups["Neuron"] doesn't have attribute inputs anymore.

These are the input names I want to put in a list. I've been able to access the float values and Input_XX number names like:
for key in bpy.data.objects[“Raft L (Microscope)”].modifiers[“GeometryNodes”].keys():
print(bpy.data.objects[“Raft L (Microscope)”].modifiers[“GeometryNodes”][key])
but I haven't been able to find the Attribute (or input) names anywhere.
I've also tried:
bpy.data.node_groups[“Neuron”].nodes
bpy.data.node_groups[“Neuron”].nodes[“Group Input”].inputs.values()
bpy.data.node_groups[“Neuron”].nodes[“Group Input”].inputs.keys()
bpy.data.node_groups[“Neuron”].nodes[“Group Input”].inputs.items()
and I couldn't find the names I'm looking for in there either.
Does anyone know how to access these Node input names?

It was: node_groups["Neuron"].inputs
It changed to node_groups["Neuron"].interface.items_tree

*So the whole line would look this way:
input_names = [input.name for input in bpy.data.node_groups["Neuron"].interface.items_tree if input.name != "Geometry"]


**But since the line became longer - it's not quite rational to keep the code as a single line anymore.
Hence I'd prefer to wright it in the multiple lines:
input_names = []

for input in bpy.data.node_groups['Neuron'].interface.items_tree:
    
    if input.name != 'Geometry':
        
        input_names.append(input.name)


but, list comprehension is faster than for loop.
